# How to count cells if it contains a value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, find, countif

I have an Excel sheet like this:

```
ID  | Relations
----+----------------
1   | ,
2   | ,
3   | ,1,
4   | ,1,2,
5   | ,2,
6   | ,3,
7   | ,1,2,4,
8   | ,1,2,4,5,6,
9   | ,2,4,5,1,
```

I want to count *Relations* as *Related Count* column - that checks if finding `,ID,` in *Relations* is true - with a formula to achieve a result like this:

```
ID  | Relations     | Related Count
----+---------------+----------------
1   | ,             | 5               '>> related in: 3,4,7,8,9
2   | ,             | 5               '>> related in: 4,5,7,8,9
3   | ,1,           | 1               '>> related in: 6
4   | ,1,2,         | 3               '>> related in: 7,8,9
5   | ,2,           | 2               '>> related in: 8,9
6   | ,3,           | 1               '>> related in: 8
7   | ,1,2,4,       | 0
8   | ,1,2,4,5,6,   | 0
9   | ,2,4,5,1,     | 0
```

**Edit:**
I know how to use `countif()` function, Please help me in finding a formula for *Related Count* column.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COUNTIF does an exact match of a value against the entire cell, it doesn't act like a "contains" function.  However, you can use wildcards as a workaround, because wildcards represent everything else within the cell.  So you can accomplish what you want with COUNTIF, and an array formula isn't required.

[image]

The formula in C2:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$10,"*,"&A2&",*")
```

This surrounds the A2 value with commas, so it isn't limited to single digits.  Then the asterisks represent anything else before or after.

Answer (score 1):

This answer will work if you've only got 9 IDs:

```
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A2,B:B)),1,0))
```

This works by looking for A2 within the contents of every cell in B - this differs from COUNTIF as that looks for the entire contents matching. The IF and ISNUMBER then returns a 1 for each cell in which the number is found and a 0 otherwise. It then uses SUM to add the 1s and 0s.

This is an array formula so after you've entered it into your worksheet you'll need to press Ctrl, Alt + Enter.

Screenshot showing this working:

[image: proof]

If you have IDs and Relations that go to 10, 11 etc. then it won't work as it will find the 1 as the first digit in 10 and affect your results for 1

Comment: You may think this is the same as countif but it really isn't. The reason it didn't work is I put the {} in the formula but Excel puts them in when you press Ctrl, Shift + Enter. I've added the screenshot showing this working. The explanation for why this is correct is already in the answer

Comment: I suspect that the problem shA.t is having is that the IDs exceed 9.  The relations in col B are always surrounded by commas, so you can eliminate the restriction by using `","&A2&","` in the FIND instead of A2.  One other suggestion: use an explicit range instead of B:B.  Recalculating the entire column can take awhile.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `=COUNTIF(Range to count; Parameter to find)` in your case let's say your dataset starts in `A1`

`=COUNTIF($B$2:$B10; $A1)` and shoud be input in column C

Cheers

Comment: I know how to use `coutif` function!, How do you thing this answers my question?

Comment: @shA.t First, I can't know that you know how to use `CountIf` as the way your question is worded. Second it does what you asked. It counts the ids and outputs the same as your example. Have you tried?

Comment: I tried it in many ways but problem is what should be `Parameter to find` in my case - The criteria will not match

Comment: It should be `$A2` then you can drag the formula

Comment: I think you didn't read my question correctly! I want to find count of cells in *Relations* column that contains *`,ID,`* in it or `concatenate(",",A2,",")` !?